# Access nested content children

Tags: angular, typescript

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[some-directive]'
})
export class SomeDirective...
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'inner-component',
  template: `
    <div some-directive></div>
  `
})
export class InnerComponent {
}
```

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <inner-component></inner-component>
  `
})
export class OuterComponent {
  @ContentChildren(SomeDirective, {descendants: true}) elementsWithDirective: QueryList<SomeDirective>;
}
```

Is this a proper way to get those directives? `elementsWithDirective` returns empty results array. I can't access it this way. The only way I can rid of the problem is to place the `<div app-some-directive></div>` directly inside OuterComponent's view but I want to avoid it.

Comment: when do you access the elementsWithDirective ? it should be set during ngAfterContentInit

Comment: Wherever I do it, even when I console ```elementsWithDirective``` after 10 seconds, the results array is still empty.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK currently there is no way to directly get grandchild elements from component. 
I don't know what is your use case, but you could:

1. Add `@ViewChild(InnerComponent) innerComponent: InnerComponent` to your outer component
2. Add `@ViewChild(SomeDirective) someDirective: SomeDirective` to your inner component
3. from outer component access your directive through inner component in ngAfterViewInit
   `ngAfterViewInit(): void {
       console.log(this.innerComponent.someDirective);
   }`

stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txahiv)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are confused with contentChildren and viewChildren. In your case, you should use viewChildren to query SomeDirective in InnerComponent, and emit results up to OuterComponent, e.g.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'outer-component',
  template: `    <inner-component 
    (elementsWithDirectiveChanges)="elementsWithDirectiveChanged($event)"> 
    </inner- 
    component>`
})
export class OuterComponent {
  elementsWithDirectiveChanged(change: any) {
    console.log(change);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'inner-component',
  template: `
    <div some-directive>inner</div>
  `
})
export class InnerComponent {
  @ViewChildren(SomeDirective) elementsWithDirective!: QueryList<SomeDirective>;
  @Output() elementsWithDirectiveChanges = new EventEmitter();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.elementsWithDirectiveChanges.emit(this.elementsWithDirective);
  }
}
```

demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2oesig?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts